# Sharepoint 2013 People Picker Change event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want People picker Change Event in Javascript as i have to do some task if user is selected/changed in people picker using ClassName.

i have tried the following

```
$(".Assignedname").bind('input propertychange', function() { 
     alert("Onchange event" ); 
})
```

this fires when i type anything (i.e. text is changed ) , but not fires when user is selected in peoples picker.
Kindly give me some solution. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Once the people picker is initialized, you can access it in the js dictionary and assign a function to the OnValueChangedClientScript property of the picker. The function accepts two parameters, where the second parameter (userInfo) is a collection of users in the picker

```
var picker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerId + "_TopSpan"];
picker.OnValueChangedClientScript = function (elementId, userInfo) {
    for (var x = 0; x < userInfo.length; x++) {
        console.log(userInfo[x].Key);
    }
    alert("Total number of " + userInfo.length + " users is selected")
};
```

Comment: A caveat about this method: I recently ran into a timing issue with Microsoft Edge where my script attaching the event handler ran before the people-picker objects had been populated, so the code failed. Make sure that `SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerId]` is initialized before you attach your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the picker id for SharePoint Client People Picker change event. I have got the same using `OnUserResolvedClientScript` as below. Here to get the picker div I have followed the approach of getting it via the people picker text box `id` and the `title name` which you can get the by inspecting the element. put the below code in  `$(document).ready` function. Happy Coding

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function() {
    var pickerDiv = $("[id^='Employee_x0020_Name'][title='Employee Name']");
    var picker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDiv[0].id];
    picker.OnUserResolvedClientScript = function(peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {
 //It will get the desired display name of the people from picker div, similarly any other property can be accessed via selectedUsersInfo
        var empname = selectedUsersInfo[0].DisplayText;
        console.log(empname);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery and a `focusout` event on the `input` field, instead, to achieve the same effect:

```
$('input[title="Title of my field"]').focusout(function() { 
    alert("Focusout event fired." ); 
    doPeoplePickerStuff();  // function for doing validation 
});
```

This has the advantage of being able to check the value of that field whenever they click on anything else - with the exception of the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button, if they click that immediately after typing in the field. Here's how I deal with that:

1. Create a new <kbd>Submit</kbd> button and hide the other one:

   `$('input[name*="diidIOSaveItem"]').parent().append('<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="doValidation()"></input>'); $('input[name*="diidIOSaveItem"]').hide();`
2. Create the `doValidation()` function for your new <kbd>Submit</kbd> button:

   `function doValidation() {`

   ```
    doPeoplePickerStuff();  // do validation on the field here
    if (personFound == true) {
        $('input[name*="diidIOSaveItem"]').click(); // clicks the real button so it does what it normally would
    }
   ```

   `}`

If you're firing the event in order to grab its value and do validation on it, use:

```
var personFound = false;
function doPeoplePickerStuff() {
    var personFieldSpan = $('span[id*="OriginalTitleOfMyField"]');
    var personFieldValue = stripExtraTextFromPeoplePicker(personFieldSpan.text());
    if (personFieldValue != "") {  // you could do comparisons against the existing value, too, by getting the original value(s) via REST call
        personFound = true;
    }
}

function stripExtraTextFromPeoplePicker(person) {
    var newPerson = person;
    console.log("Span text: " + newPerson);
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('Title of my field','');
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('Enter a name or email address...','');
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('Enter names or email addresses...','');
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('xSuggestions are available. Use up and down arrows to select.','');
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('Suggestions are available. Use up and down arrows to select.','');
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('\r','');
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('\n','');
    newPerson = newPerson.replace('\t','');
    newPerson = newPerson.trim();
    return newPerson;
}
```